# This value is overwritten Google maps in react component

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

My component code is as below:

```
export default class map extends React.Component {
    drwmap() {
        let mapOptions = {
            zoom: zoom,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng),
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
            },
            streetViewControl: true,
            minZoom: 2,
        };
        // here also this.lat and this.lng are not avilable
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), mapOptions);
    }
    loadmap(event) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': this.place}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                let lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                let lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                // here this is window looks google map modified scope and I dont have access to this of react
                this.lat = lat;
                this.lng = lng;
                this.drwmap();
            }
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadmap();
    }
}
```

I am getting this as window value when I do geocoding with Google maps in reactjs. It looks like googlemaps is overwriting it with some other value and scope of this in react is not available.

How can I make this available so that I can use common variable across the component?

Comment: I have reformatted your code sample to have cleaner block nesting. It is always a good idea to clean up the code sample as much as you can, because if it is easy to read, you are much more likely to get people who will take the time to read it and try to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using arrow functions in react.

```
this.geocoder.geocode({'address': this.place},(results, status) => {
/ / here this is available as component
});
```